NextJS - Authentication - Refresh logic in middleware with custom backend
How do I implement a refresh mechanism for authentication in NextJS with a custom backend?
My plan so far was to

Decode the access token and refresh token from cookies
If the access token expired but the refresh token is still valid, then I want to refresh my access token
At the end I want to set the currentUser in a separate cookie from the decoded access token (also this doesn't seem to work)

My code
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import authService from './app/lib/auth.service'

const protectedRoutes = ['/dashboard']
const publicRoutes = ['/login', '/register', '/']

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const res = NextResponse.next()
    const path = req.nextUrl.pathname
    const isProtectedRoute = protectedRoutes.includes(path)
    const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(path)

    const isAuthorized = !isProtectedRoute || checkIfAuthorized(req, res)

    // Redirect to /login if the user is not authenticated
    if (isProtectedRoute && !isAuthorized) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', req.nextUrl))
    }

    // Redirect to /dashboard if the user is authenticated and is trying to access a public route
    if (isPublicRoute && isAuthorized && !req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/')) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', req.nextUrl))
    }

    return NextResponse.next()
}

const checkIfAuthorized = (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
    const accessToken = req.cookies.get('accessToken')?.value
    if (!accessToken) return false

    // check expiration
    const decodedAccessToken = jwt.decode(accessToken) as any
    if (!decodedAccessToken) return false

    const accessExpiredAt = new Date(decodedAccessToken?.exp * 1000)
    const now = new Date()
    if (accessExpiredAt < now) {
        // we have to refresh
        const refreshToken = req.cookies.get('refreshToken')?.value
        if (!refreshToken) return false

        const decodedRefreshToken = jwt.decode(refreshToken) as any
        const refreshExpiredAt = new Date(decodedRefreshToken?.exp * 1000)
        if (refreshExpiredAt < now) return false
        
        // TODO: refresh - how? I cannot use async functions here?
        // await authService.refresh()
    }

    // set user if it's not set
    if (!req.cookies.get('currentUser')?.value) {
        // TODO: how? the following doesn't set the cookie
        req.cookies.set('currentUser', JSON.stringify(decodedAccessToken))
        res.cookies.set('currentUser', JSON.stringify(decodedAccessToken))
    }

    return true
}

// Routes Middleware should not run on (e.g. images)
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
}


I advice you to do this in auth.ts file. Much easier.

i think you are trying to achieve something like this:
https://github.com/hidayahapriliansyah/handle-cookie-http-only-next-express/blob/main/next/src/middleware.ts
you can make middleware as async and make an api call there.
